# If there is a style.css and a style.min.css and I link to style.css will the browser every use the .min.css?

Tags: css, minify

Just wanted to check this:

If I have Style.css and Style.min.css (in the same directory) and my html page references Style.css will the browser/server every download the Style.min.css instead?
(like if they have the same "last modified" date, etc.)?

Answer (score 0):

No, it will use what is specified. Why should it use something else?